# How to use Gluon Mobile Theme for a Desktop JavaFX Project?

Tags: java, javafx, gluon

In the Scene Builder I can choose for preview a JavaFX Theme called "Gluon Mobile". How can I set the Gluon Mobile theme for my desktop app by code?

What I have:

```
setUserAgentStylesheet(STYLESHEET_CASPIAN); // default theme
```

What I want:

```
setUserAgentStylesheet("SOME_GLUON_THEME_PATH");
```

**OBS:** I don't want a Gluon Project for Desktop/Mobile, I just want to use the Gluon Theme.

Sorry for the dumb question, but I did some research and didn't find out how.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your motivation is, so I'll put this out there in case you're interested in Material Design. You can use the [JFoenix material design library](http://www.jfoenix.com/) for a very sharp looking application. I'm not affiliated with JFoenix in any way, by the way.